# How to extract strings before, between and after different patterns with r?

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a way to extract from a dataframe column several words before, between and after several patterns...

Let's focus on the first two rows for instance:

```
[1] "keyword1 / keyword2 [keyword3 - keyword4 - keyword5 - keyword6][keyword7]"
[2] "keyword1[keyword3]"
```

how could I extract all those keywords and store them in a dataframe or a list ?

So far I tried this (which is far from enough...)

```
library(stringr)

a = "keyword1 / keyword2 [keyword3 - keyword4 - keyword5 - keyword6][keyword7]"

str_extract(a, "[^/]+")

str_extract_all(a,"(?<=/).+(?= \\[)")

str_extract_all(a,"(?<=\\[).+(?= \\/)")

str_extract_all(a,"(?<=\\]\\[).+(?=\\])")
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `str_extract_all(a, "\\w+")`, to extract all words? What is the expected result? Or, do you want to extract all words inside square brackets?

Comment: Your solution did the trick ! Sorry I didn't know it was possible to do that so simply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you plan to extract all words from a string you can simply use

```r
str_extract_all(a, '\\w+')
```

If you plan to only match words that contain letters or digits, then you need to subtract connector punctuation, diacritics and some more chars from [`\w` pattern](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) (note that, in `stringr` with ICU regex engine behind the scenes, `\w` = `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]`):

```r
str_extract_all(a, '[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Decimal_Number}]+')
```

You may require word boundaries on both ends of the "word" in the latter case with `\b`:

```r
str_extract_all(a, '\\b[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Decimal_Number}]+\\b')
```

Or a shorter

```r
str_extract_all(a, '\\b[\\p{L}\\d]+\\b')
```

You may further experiment with the pattern to fit it your idea of what a "word" is.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer ! What about compounds words ?
```a = "keyword one / keyword2 [keyword3 - keyword4 - keyword five - keyword6][keyword7]"``` ?
Can I extract them as a single word (eg: "keyword one" rather than "keyword" "one") ?

Comment: @Linda That is not a compound word, these are word sequences separated with whitespace. So, use `'\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*'`.